# Safe to Repair NTFS Drive/Partitions When Paragon Is Installed

Tags: partition

Is is safe to repair NTFS drive/partitions with Paragon installed? I don't have access to windows anymore and can't format them

Comment: Disk utility is not designed to fix NTFS volumes.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to use Disk Utility to add/delete partitions on a drive that is partitioned in MBR or GUID. As long as paragon followed the standards, you won't have any issues.

Do note that NTFS volumes are left alone by Disk Utility so you won't be changing them - just deleting and erasing or working in the free space around them.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try it. I did it and now I have a found.000 folder on my external drive that replaced everything that was on it.